# Displaying and editing XML data tree in nested uitableviews on iOS

Tags: ios, xml, uitableview, tree, nested

I need solution to display XML data tree (stored as plist) via UITableview on iOS

It's desirable to have:

- ability to display XML data tree in nested tables
- ability to re-arrange nodes in XML tree using WYSIWYG principle
- ability to add new nodes and copy-paste existing

Any ready-to-use snippets/libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason why you'd want to use nested tables rather than a single table with indented rows? The single table approach should be much easier to set up and manage.

[TLIndexPathTools](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools) has a great example of a hierarchical table with expandable levels. Try running the [Outline sample project](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools/blob/master/Examples/Outline/Outline/OutlineTableViewController.m). TLIndexPathTools is a low-level library, so it should be easy to modify to your specific needs.

Comment: No any particular reason. Just a willing to do it as quick as possible.
TLindexPathTools looks great though, would use it next time.
If there is a straight way to re-order rows?

Comment: Sorting in general is easy. The `TLIndexPathController` accepts sort descriptors. And you can sort the array of items before putting them in the controller. It doesn't currently address sorting in a hierarchy specifically, but you could do it by overriding the initializer of `TLTreeDataModel` and sorting the items there.

Comment: I could add a sort descriptor property to `TLIndexPathTreeItem` and have the initializer for `TLTreeDataModel` sort the children of the given item with the descriptor.

Comment: Yep, was managed to do that. Nice, will use it.

Though, will keep nested table too, 
as they still do the thing,
'if something works - do not touch it' )

Comment: Found another good solution which uses JSON 
https://github.com/liuminqian/SvpplyTable

Comment: Looks like after iOS7 launch, my solution doesn't work. Timothy, not sure if this is a good place, what is the best way to map  NSArray tree of dictionaries to TLTreeDataModel?

Comment: You'd iterate over your data and build up a tree of `TLIndexPathTreeItem` objects with your data assigned to the `data` property. Then you pass the array of `TLIndexPathTreeItems` to the constructor of `TLTreeDataModel`.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: given solution doesn't work with iOS7 and greater**

Did not found good solution nowhere, so made it by myself.

It uses nested UITableView in recursive mode.
Features:

- displaying of XML data tree of any depth
- supports custom sizes, rotation and both iPad/iPhone screens
- supports re-arranging (move node up, move node down, delete, copy-paste, create new)

[image]
[image]

https://github.com/braginets/NestedTablesForXMLDataTree

NB: I am aware that this solution maybe not perfect, it's rather an attempt to make my modest input into this great community to thank for all for their knowledge sharing.